# bulk update the external list sharepoint 2010

Tags: external-content-type, external-list

I try to provide bulk editing and updating for external lists. 
I heard that the datasheet view is a convenient tool, but it is not enabled for external lists. Is there any way to get an easy, user-friendly bulk editing going?

My external list has 3000 fields and do not make sense to update one by one. Please let me know better way to bulk update/edit list

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible with OOTB.

Did you try to Edit with Access 2010?

But their is one solution from Code plex and they claim it works for the External List as well.

[SharePoint 2010 Batch Edit](https://sp2010batchedit.codeplex.com/discussions/355796)